# In Ubuntu terminal I want to change the color depending on git status --porcelain

Tags: linux, bash, git, ubuntu

When I add some change in the local repo I want the color to change from green to red when I press the enter key. It doesn't seem to work with my code

I have this code in my .bashrc

```
function parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}


function git_status_color() {
  local git_status="$(git status --porcelain)"
  if [ -n "$git_status" ]; then
    echo -e "$RED"
  else
    echo -e "$GREEN"
  fi
}

 
RED="\[\033[01;31m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[01;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[01;32m\]"
BLUE="\[\033[01;34m\]"
NO_COLOR="\[\033[00m\]"


PS1="$GREEN\u$NO_COLOR:$BLUE\w $(git_status_color)\$(parse_git_branch)$NO_COLOR\$ "
```

Comment: I think you need to escape the `$`, otherwise the `git_status_color` will only be executed exactly when PS1 is set. Verify that by doing `echo $PS1` (it'll show the output of `git_status_color` instead of the command). Switching to `\$(...)` should work.

Comment: (Sidenote: to get current branch, you might want to simply use `git rev-parse HEAD` rather than parsing it yourself from `git branch` output.)

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work

```
function update_git_status() {
  GIT_STATUS=$(git status --porcelain)
}

RED="\033[01;31m"
GREEN="\033[01;32m"
BLUE="\[\033[01;34m\]"
NO_COLOR="\[\033[00m\]"

function git_status_color() {
  if [[ $GIT_STATUS ]]; then
    echo -en $RED
  else
    echo -en $GREEN
  fi
}

function git_remote_status() {
  if [[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
    if [[ $(git cherry -v) ]]; then
      echo -en " \u21E7"
    fi
    if [[ $(git rev-list --left-right --count @{u}...HEAD | awk '{print $1}') -gt 0 ]]; then
      echo -en " \u21E9"
    fi
  fi
}

function parse_git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}

PS1="$GREEN\u$NO_COLOR:$BLUE\w $NO_COLOR\$(git_status_color)\$(parse_git_branch)\[$NO_COLOR\]\$(git_remote_status) \$ "

PROMPT_COMMAND="update_git_status; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: please comment your code